# Executing a view tells me that I have no permissions on some of its functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've created a limited user that will retrieve data using views, so it doesn't have access to the entire database.

But when I grant him "select" permision to the intended view it returns an error that it doesn't have permission to some of the functions used in the view. Although it has no problem with some other functions.

If I grant him "execute" permission to those functions then it works fine, but my question is why I needed to grant him execute permissions on some functions while the rest didn't need them ?.

I can't see any difference between the functions that worked from the start and the functions that needed additional permisions. They are all normal user functions on the same dbo schema.

All the objects involved (views, tables and functions) pertain to the same database and schema: dbo.

What should I look in order to make the view work with just permissions on the view ?.

This is the view (it's a huge ugly view I've inherited):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[EXCEL_LLIBRETA_MAGICA_COMANDES_PENDENTS_V] AS 

-- Aquesta consulta esta basada en COMANDES_PENDENTS, i l'hen expandit per a afegir el Representant, utilitzar la funció f_comanda_bloquejada per a calcular BloqAdmon, ...

SELECT LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre, CapsaleraComandesVendes.Numero,
       --Isnull( LiniesComandesVendes.ColorExterior,'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,liniesComandesVendes.GruixExterior)),'') ColorExterior,
       --Isnull(LiniesComandesVendes.ColorInterior,'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,LiniesComandesVendes.GruixInterior)),'') ColorInterior,
       Isnull(Isnull(dbo.f_consum_color_Exterior(LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),LiniesComandesVendes.ColorExterior),'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,Isnull(dbo.f_consum_Gruix_Exterior(liniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),liniesComandesVendes.GruixExterior))),'') ColorExterior,
       Isnull(Isnull(dbo.f_consum_color_Interior(LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),LiniesComandesVendes.ColorInterior),'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,Isnull(dbo.f_consum_Gruix_Interior(liniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),LiniesComandesVendes.GruixInterior))),'') ColorInterior,
       /*max(LiniesComandesVendes.LongitudSolape) LongitudSolape,*/
       max(case when Isnull(LongitudSolape,0)>0 and Isnull(LongitudSolape,0)<9999 then RIGHT('    '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Floor(LongitudSolape)),4)+' DEL' 
                else case when Isnull(LongitudSolapeTra,0)>0 and Isnull(LongitudSolapeTra,0)<9999 then RIGHT('    '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Floor(LongitudSolapeTra)),4)+' TRA' 
                          else '' 
                     end 
           end) LongitudSolape,
       dbo.f_RetornaReferenciaFabricant(Articles.ReferenciaFabricant, CapsaleraComandesVendes.Client)  ReferenciaFabricant,    
       CapsaleraComandesVendes.Referencia, CapsaleraAgenda.Nom, CapsaleraComandesVendes.Data,
       OrdresFabricacio.Estat, OrdresFabricacio.DataFabricacio,
       sum(LiniesComandesVendes.quantitatMetres) quantitatMetres,
       sum( LiniesComandesVendes.quantitatMetres - dbo.f_quantitatFabricadaLCV(LiniesComandesVendes.identificadorLinia) )  quantitatMetresPendentsFab,
       case when dbo.f_ordre_te_Inserts(LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre)=1 then '# INSERTS #' else '' end +
       convert(varchar(250),case when OrdresFabricacio.DataEntrega is not null then '#'+CONVERT(varchar(8),OrdresFabricacio.dataEntrega,3)+'#' 
                                 else '' 
                            end +
                            OrdresFabricacio.observacions) observacions,
       dbo.f_comanda_confirmada( CapsaleraComandesVendes.Numero ) confirmada_client,
       max(LiniesComandesVendes.perfilExterior)perfilExterior,
       max(LiniesComandesVendes.perfilInterior) perfilInterior,
       case when dbo.f_comanda_bloquejada(CapsaleraComandesVendes.Numero) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as BloqAdmon,
       --convert(bit, dbo.f_comanda_bloquejada(CapsaleraComandesVendes.Numero)) BloqAdmon,
       CASE WHEN iSNULL(OrdresFabricacio.esperarMinims,0)=1 THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END esperar_fer_minims,
       AgendaRepresentant.Nom as Representant, coalesce(CapsaleraComandesVendes.DataEntrega, OrdresFabricacio.DataEntrega) as DataEntrega,
       OrdresFabricacio.revisada, OrdresFabricacio.observacions as ObservacionsOrdre,
       substring(CapsaleraComandesVendes.Observacions, 1, 1000) as ObservacionsComanda,
       substring(CapsaleraComandesVendes.ObservacionsEnvio, 1, 1000) as ObservacionsEnvio

FROM GESTIO1.dbo.Articles Articles, 
     GESTIO1.dbo.CapsaleraAgenda CapsaleraAgenda, 
     GESTIO1.dbo.CapsaleraComandesVendes CapsaleraComandesVendes
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CapsaleraAgenda as AgendaRepresentant on AgendaRepresentant.Codi = CapsaleraComandesVendes.Representant
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTS on CLIENTS.agenda=Isnull(CapsaleraComandesVendes.facturarA,CapsaleraComandesVendes.client),
     GESTIO1.dbo.LiniesComandesVendes LiniesComandesVendes, 
     gestio1.dbo.OrdresFabricacio OrdresFabricacio

WHERE CapsaleraComandesVendes.Numero = LiniesComandesVendes.Numero AND
      Articles.Codi = LiniesComandesVendes.Article AND 
      CapsaleraComandesVendes.Client = CapsaleraAgenda.Codi AND 
      --LiniesComandesVendes.Numero = OrdresFabricacio.comanda  
      LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre = OrdresFabricacio.NumeroOrdre AND
      LiniesComandesVendes.Numero>=2500000 AND 
      OrdresFabricacio.DataFabricacio Is Null AND
      ( Isnull(LiniesComandesVendes.QuantitatServida,0)<LiniesComandesVendes.Quantitat  OR Isnull(CapsaleraComandesVendes.facturada_sense_servir,0)=1  ) AND
      CapsaleraComandesVendes.finalitzada='N' AND
      CapsaleraComandesVendes.data>'1/1/2011' AND
      ( Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'CT%' or
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'CP%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'ST%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'F%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'OD%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'RH%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'CL%'  or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'XT%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'YT%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'AW%' or 
       Articles.ReferenciaFabricant like 'LR-[0-9]%' ) AND
      Isnull(Articles.tipusProducte,'') not in ('CP','RM','AL','TR','CO') AND
      Isnull(OrdresFabricacio.fabricacioExterna,0)<>1
 
group by LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre, CapsaleraComandesVendes.Numero, 
         --Isnull( LiniesComandesVendes.ColorExterior,'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,liniesComandesVendes.GruixExterior)),'') ,
         --Isnull(LiniesComandesVendes.ColorInterior,'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,LiniesComandesVendes.GruixInterior)),''),
         Isnull(Isnull(dbo.f_consum_color_Exterior(LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),LiniesComandesVendes.ColorExterior),'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,Isnull(dbo.f_consum_Gruix_Exterior(liniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),liniesComandesVendes.GruixExterior))),'') ,
         Isnull(Isnull(dbo.f_consum_color_Interior(LiniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),LiniesComandesVendes.ColorInterior),'')+'-'+Isnull(convert(varchar,convert(float,Isnull(dbo.f_consum_Gruix_Interior(liniesComandesVendes.NumeroOrdre),LiniesComandesVendes.GruixInterior))),'') ,
         dbo.f_RetornaReferenciaFabricant(Articles.ReferenciaFabricant, CapsaleraComandesVendes.Client), 
         CapsaleraComandesVendes.Referencia, CapsaleraAgenda.Nom, CapsaleraComandesVendes.Data, OrdresFabricacio.Estat, OrdresFabricacio.DataFabricacio,
         CapsaleraComandesVendes.autoritzarFabricacio,clients.impagats,capsaleraComandesVendes.situacioRisc,OrdresFabricacio.DataEntrega,OrdresFabricacio.observacions,
         CASE WHEN iSNULL(OrdresFabricacio.esperarMinims,0)=1 THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END,
         AgendaRepresentant.Nom, coalesce(CapsaleraComandesVendes.DataEntrega, OrdresFabricacio.DataEntrega), OrdresFabricacio.revisada,
         substring(CapsaleraComandesVendes.Observacions, 1, 1000), substring(CapsaleraComandesVendes.ObservacionsEnvio, 1, 1000)

GO
```

This is one of the functions that doesn't demand to get execution permissions granted.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[f_quantitatFabricadaLCV](@identificador integer) returns decimal(18,2) as
BEGIN

Declare @quantitatFabricada decimal(18,2)

    Select @quantitatFabricada=sum(PP2.quantitat) 
    from PartesProduccioComandes PP2 
         LEft outer join PartesProduccioOrdres PPO on PPO.Identificador=PP2.OrdreParte 
         Left outer join PartesProduccioCapsalera PPC on (PPC.Parte=PPO.Parte)  
    where PP2.idLiniaComanda=@identificador
             and PP2.seleccionat=1 and PPC.estat in ('F','Z') 
   
   return Isnull( @quantitatFabricada,0)         
END
```

And this is one sample of the functions that demand to get execution permission granted in order for the view to open.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_consum_color_exterior]  ( @numeroOrdre integer) 
RETURNS varchar(10)
BEGIN 
  Declare @COL varchar(10)

            SELECT  top 1 
            @Col=Articles.color
            from OrdresFabricacioConsum
                 INNER JOIN ORDRESFabricacio on (OrdresFabricacioConsum.NumeroOrdre=ORDRESFAbricacio.numeroOrdre)                        
                 INNER JOIN Articles on (Articles.codi=OrdresFabricacioConsum.article)
                 INNER JOIN tipusBobines TB on (TB.tipusBobina=articles.tipusBobina)
            Where Isnull(articles.tipusBobina,'')<>'' and Articles.Codi<>'#PENDIENTE#'
                  and intExt='E' and OrdresFabricacioConsum.numeroOrdre=@NumeroOrdre and Isnull(Articles.gruix,0)<>0 and idLiniaComanda is null AND iSNULL(OrdresFabricacio.tipusOrdre,0)<>3
            order by OrdresFabricacioConsum.identificador   

  return @col                           
END
```

Thank you.

**Edit:**

For now I have created a dbExecutor role, just on the dbo schema, so the views can execute any function. I don't like that they can also execute any stored procedure, but at least being assigned to the schema they don't seem able to retrieve the list of procedures.

```
create ROLE [db_executor]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE on SCHEMA::DBO TO db_executor
GO
```

Comment: Are the functions in the same schema as the view? Perhaps the ownership chain is broken.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, all of them pertain to the same schema. Yes, my google search tells me that this probably is a broken ownership chain, but isn't "dbo" the owner of all those objects ?.

Comment: Usually the object owner is inherited from the schema owner but can be overridden with `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`. Check with `SELECT USER_NAME(principal_id), name, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE principal_id IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: @DanGuzman your query gives me an empty result, and this other query that I've found in google tells me that all of them are owned by dbo : SELECT s.name + '.' + o.name AS ObjectName, COALESCE(p.name, p2.name) AS OwnerName
FROM sys.all_objects o
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals p ON o.principal_id = p.principal_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals p2 ON s.principal_id = p2.principal_id
WHERE s.name NOT IN ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
ORDER BY 1

Comment: Are all the objects in the same database?

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, they are all on the same database.

Comment: Hmm, that rules out the usual suspects. I suggest you create a minimal example that demonstrates the issue and add that to your question. Barring a SQL Server bug, there is likely a detail I haven't considered.

Comment: Is it a scalar or table inline function ?

Comment: @SQLpro All of them are escalar functions

Comment: can you put all the stuff in DDL statements ? Did your SQL scalar functions contains systems table or functions ?

Answer (score 2):

the system table *all_objects* uses references to system objects at the master levels. This is, I think, the reason why.

Ordinary user should never access to system tables!

This is why the SQL standard (la norme SQL) impose l'utilisation des vues INFORMATION_SCHEMA qui sont d'ordre "public"

En tout état de cause, récrivez votre requête comme suit :

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS OBJECT_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME, TABLE_TYPE AS OBJECT_TYPE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA AS OBJECT_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

Comment: Thanks @SQLPro, but the view (or its functions) don't really use system tables (the query that I quoted on the comments, was the one that I used to verify that all the functions got the same dbo owner). I've added the real view query on the question, but I don't really think that it would be much useful, it's a huge ugly view that I've inherited. All the tables and functions consulted are normal tables and functions on the same database and schema. I would have to add the DDL to construct all the tables for it to be useful, and I don't think that anyone wants to read that.

Comment: You can also cross post in developpez.com / forums MS SQL Server

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that this problem comes from being an old SQL Server 2005 database that has been upgraded and expanded many times until now, to run on SQL Server 2017. Although I see the same owner on all those objects, probably the ownership chain was broken on some of those upgrades to a new SQL Server.